# What is a non-defensive method in java?

Tags: java

I am stuck on a mock exam question.

I have written the class below and it works.  However, within the body of the `powN` method, I need to use a `for(){}` loop. Also I need to use a non-defensive definition of `powN`.

Here are my questions. How can I use a for loop? What is a non-defensive method and how can it be used in `powN`?

```
public class Power {
    private double x = 0;

    Power(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double powN(int n) {
        return Math.pow(getX(), n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Power p = new Power(5.0);
        double d = p.powN(2);
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the non defensive bit just to use an exception to catch rogue values?

Comment: defensive / non defensive: http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~ar3/lectures/IndustrialMaster/SoftwareEngineering/L5/Lecture5.pdf (slide 16)

Comment: I think that "non-defensive" term is something your professor made up.  Programmers are likely to be familiar with "defensive programming" as a general concept that means making a program robust against bad input or unusual conditions, but the specific definition given on slide 16 of your lecture is not an industry-wide "established" definition.

Comment: @Wyzard, not my lecture, not my professor, I googled for "non-defensive java". I've never heard of "non-defensive" myself ;)

Comment: @RC., ah, sorry, I'd assumed without looking that the link was posted by the person who asked the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read the slide about *defensive/non-defensive* approach from your materials. I guess your professor wants you to check if the parameters are valid. Like this:

```
  public double powN(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only positive values are supported");
    }
    double tmp = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      tmp = tmp * getX();
    }
    return tmp;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question is how could i use a for loop

I am not familiar with java syntax, but the idea is:

```
public double powN(int n) {

    double tmp=1;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        tmp=tmp*getX();
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

no idea what non-defensive means

Comment: will not compile - tmp should be double.

Answer (score 1):

Non-defensive just means you are not specifically coding to check for errors such as if n == 0, return 0.

Instead you just take whatever n is and use it's value in your for loop.

So instead of using the built in Math function, just write a For loop to do the same thing it does.

```
double result = 0.0
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
   result = result * x;
}
```

Comment: `result=1;` at init. then `result=result*x;` in loop

Comment: `result = x * x;` so u r calculating just square?

Comment: Yeah, Gir is right, it would be result = result * x; I thought I maybe had that wrong.

Comment: You should edit to fix your incorrect code rather than just adding a comment.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. I forgot about that. Thanks for the comment.